# Adding an id code into input value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this html code for displaying geolocation :

```
<span id="currentLat"></span>, <span id="currentLon"></span>
```

combined with javascript code it works perfectly.
The problem is i want to display above value in a textfield.

I did try :

```
<input id="" value="<span id="currentLat"></span>, <span id="currentLon"></span>" size="30" />
```

but it give me error. How i add the value into the textfield value?

NB:

I add the javascript code used to know exactly what's wrong with the code, but maybe the code cannot be working in the text input field.

```
<script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var startPos;

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            startPos = position;
            document.getElementById("startLat").innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("startLon").innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
          }, function(error) {
            alert("Error occurred. Error code: " + error.code);
            // error.code can be:
            //   0: unknown error
            //   1: permission denied
            //   2: position unavailable (error response from locaton provider)
            //   3: timed out
          });

          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
            document.getElementById("currentLat").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("currentLon").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML =
              calculateDistance(startPos.coords.latitude, startPos.coords.longitude,
                                position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          });
        }
      };

      // Reused code - copyright Moveable Type Scripts - retrieved May 4, 2010.
      // http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
      // Under Creative Commons License http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
      function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var R = 6371; // km
        var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
        var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        var d = R * c;
        return d;
      }
      Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: cannot add an element into an input

Comment: try single quotes? `value="<span id='currentLat'></span>, <span id='currentLon'></span>"`

Comment: @roullie. why don't you try first?

Comment: You id attribute is missing the double quotes. Change to this:

<input id="" value="<span id='currentLat'></span>, <span id='currentLon'></span>" size="30" />

Comment: sorry forgot to add thhe double quotes, just edit the code. Your code indeed adding the code to input field but the javascript function not working

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** see the running code

```html
<input value='<span id=\"currentLat\"></span>, <span id=\"currentLon\"></span>' size="30" />

 <input value="<span id='currentLat'></span>, <span id='currentLon'></span>" size="30" />
```

And if you want to set width and height then it should be

```
  style="height:100px;width:200px"
```

Comment: like the comment above by Danish Bhayani.  please test your code first before commenting

Comment: The code added into the text field but the javascript function not working, no latitude and longitude value appear.

Answer (score 0):

You have there typos (unclosed quotes at `ID` attribute). Than you need to set just `span`'s content, not whole elements.

```
<input id="result" value="" size="30" />

<script>

var res = document.getElementById('result');
var lat = document.getElementById('currentLat');
var lon = document.getElementById('currentLon'); 

res.value = lat.innerText + ', ' + lon.innerText;

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zc7pLcoq/

Comment: i try the snipet above but it only generate the comma value ( , )

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape them properly  -

```
<input value='<span id="currentLat"></span>, <span id="currentLon"></span>'>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1fyLsjg/)

Comment: same, the code added into the field but the javascript function not working